# Receive an image from server using webservice

Tags: android, web-services

I have coded an app in Android which any process get data from MySQL by webservice. Now I want to receive an Image from server but I don't know what should I do? I read some topic and came to know that it should be using MTOM (I'm using apache axis2 to deploy ws) but I can't execute it successfully. Someone please give me the solution, if you can give me the demo, it would be  very helpful for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should try first. then if u face any error then ask for help. no one give direct help or code.

Comment: yep, I think that I will return URL image in server then android get it easily. Is it ok?

Comment: yeah.. then will return url. u should use image loader for that.

Answer (score 1):

1) First convert your image into a byte array, then encode it into a base64 string and pass this data to the server, save as a BLOB type. (Results in huge space requirements)

2)Save the image on the SDCard, ftp it to your server, assign an id to the image for future reference ( This method is more fast, relevant in lazy load of list view)

Answer (score 0):

Please search for AQuery that will help you to implement what you want neatly....mere 4 lines of code.